# PHP: What are the currently used Column Oriented Databases

Tags: php, database

What are the currently used Column Based Databases that work with PHP?
and are any of them free?

Comment: what do you mean by Column Based Databases?

Comment: http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/print/9034619/Relational_database_pioneer_says_technology_is_obsolete

Comment: That article reads like bullshit from someone trying to sell his own product. Shoddy journalism.

Comment: well to be honest i did not get the idea from that article, it was the first example i fetched from the net, i actually need a column-oriented database for a application I'm making, so i thought id ask which one i should use if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to know about NoSQL databases and not Column Oriented DBs.

Both are often called as the [NoSQL databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL), most of the implementations are free but the most popular in the PHP community must be [MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB).

Comment: very very interesting, ill have a read and look closer and later check back.

Comment: so far you are correct in thinking that i was looking for noSQL databases, its just that i did not know the name :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a rather large list of [Column Oriented Databases at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS). I know that at least Infobright offers a Community Edition of their product and it works with MySql. There was a [webinar recently at Zend](http://www.zend.com/en/company/news/event/webinar-developing-high-performance-analytic-applications-with-infobright-and-php) as well.